How to pass an object via RTK Query to Express backend
I've managed to send a single value which worked fine, however now that I want to send multiple values I cannot.
filterSlice:
const initialState = {
    searchTerm: "",
    category: "all",
};
...

RTK Query:
getRecipes: builder.query({
            query: (filter) => ({
                url: "/api/recipes",
                params: { filter },
            }),
            providesTags: ["Recipes"],
        }),

and in my component I have:
const filter = useSelector((state) => state.filter);
console.log(filter); // {searchTerm: '', category: 'all'}

So to send this I've tried:
const {
        data: recipes,
        error,
        isLoading,
    } = useGetRecipesQuery({
        searchTerm: filter.searchTerm,
        category: filter.category,
    });

and
... 
= useGetRecipesQuery({
        ...filter
    });

and
= useGetRecipesQuery(filter);

but whatever I try, in the express route when I do:
console.log(req.query.filter.searchTerm, req.query.filter.category);

I get: undefined undefined
How can I get those values in req?

In the outgoing request, what is the Request value? In other words, what is the value of the search parameters? You are trying to send an object that is likely being stringified, or worse, simply .toString'd, when composing the Request object. Check what your browser is sending out.

@DrewReese http://localhost:3000/api/recipes?filter=%5Bobject+Object%5D

I suspect the filter object is being stringified in the Request object. You could flatten the params you are sending so they are passed as individual search parameters, e.g. "/api/recipes?searchTerm=&category=all".
getRecipes: builder.query({
  query: (filter) => ({
    url: "/api/recipes",
    params: filter, // { searchTerm: '', category: 'all' }
  }),
  providesTags: ["Recipes"],
}),

or
getRecipes: builder.query({
  query: (filter) => ({
    url: "/api/recipes",
    params: { ...filter }, // { searchTerm: '', category: 'all' }
  }),
  providesTags: ["Recipes"],
}),

or be more explicit about what is passed:
getRecipes: builder.query({
  query: (filter) => ({
    url: "/api/recipes",
    params: {
      searchTerm: filter.searchTerm,
      category: filter.category,
    }, // { searchTerm: '', category: 'all' }
  }),
  providesTags: ["Recipes"],
}),

In the backend the parameters should be accessed directly:
console.log(req.query.searchTerm, req.query.category);

